# Socket IO is being triggered twice within useEffect

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I'm running into this issue with an app I'm building where socket IO events are being emitted twice within useEffect and I just can't seem to find what is causing useEffect to run a second time.

Here is the code I have so far:

client side:

`const socket = useRef();`

```
 useEffect(() => {
    // Create socket connection
    socket.current = io(SOCKET_URL, {
      query: { gameID: gameID },
    });

    socket.current.off("join-game").on("join-game", (player) => {
      console.log("new player:", player);
      setPlayers((players) => [...players, player]);
    });

    socket.current.off("leave-game").on("leave-game", (player) => {
      console.log("user left:", player);
      setPlayers(players.filter((p) => p.username !== player.username));
    });
 });

    return () => {
      socket.current.off("join-game");
      socket.current.off("leave-game");
}, [setPlayers, gameID, players, setPlayer]);
```

```
const joiningGame = async (user) => {
    await fetchGame();
    const player = new Player(user.username, game.current.startingHealth, 0, 0);
    setPlayer(player);
    await joinGame({ gameID: gameID, player: player }).then(({ data }) => {
      if (data) {
        socket.current.emit("join-game", player);
        setPlayers((players) => [...players, player]);
      }
    });
  };
```

server side:

```
  socket.on("join-game", (player) => {
    console.log(player, 'is joining');
    io.to(gameID).emit("join-game", player);
  });
```

I've removed restrict mode and have tried socket.disconnect() within the useEffect() return which causes none of the socket events to work. I've also tried having the client emits within return and the socket.off() outside of return.

Comment: Do you need players as a dependency for your useEffect? It looks like that's being set within it, and therefore triggering the useEffect again

Comment: Tried without players as a dependency and it still causes it to render twice. Tried it with empty dependency as well and same issue.